# How to upload an artifact to some folder inside a remote machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, github-actions

I m completely new to github actions and not sure in which direction I should search for help so posting my problem here.

I have a vm running on azure. I have a github action which is generating an artifact on push, lets say myPackage.zip. I want to to extract it and paste into a folder C:/path/to/my/app/

I can access my vm using remote desktop as its windows based machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this action: https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact

It allows uploading any file from any system into build artifacts.

Comment: I need to upload into remote machine's directory not into build artifacts